# What does docker build --network host actually do?

Tags: docker

What does the option `--network host` actually do in`docker build --network host .`?   What behaves differently for having the option set vice the default?

Answer (score 7):

The `--network` flag specifies which Network mode is used for the `RUN` commands during build.

[From the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.25/#operation/ImageBuild)

> Sets the networking mode for the run commands during build. Supported
> standard values are: bridge, host, none, and container:<name|id>. Any
> other value is taken as a custom network's name to which this
> container should connect to.

By default, docker uses the [bridge](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/) network driver, which connects the containers to a network separate from the host. If you instead [use host networking](https://docs.docker.com/network/host/) the network stack of the container is not isolated from the host.